# c++ lambda, cannot access variable captured by copy

Tags: c++, lambda

I have this simple client/server socket code that sends and receives a lambda function. Problem is on the client inside recvlambda() function, when I try to invoke the lambda after receiving it, I get seg fault @

> printf("Hello World! %i, %i\n", x, y);

Debugging reveals that x and y cannot be accessed, the memory address for them is bad.

I am using gcc 4.8.1 on Ubuntu 13.10.

I am passing x, y by copy to the lambda in the sendlambda() function. This should not seg fault. Any idea why?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <gmpxx.h>

using namespace std;

typedef int (*func)();

/* Server code in C */

  #include <sys/types.h>
  #include <sys/socket.h>
  #include <netinet/in.h>
  #include <arpa/inet.h>
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <string.h>
  #include <unistd.h>
#include <functional>

void sendlambda(int ConnectFD)
{
    int x = 2342342;
    int y = 23454234;
    function<int (void)> f = [x, y]() mutable -> int
    {
       printf("Hello World! %i, %i\n", x, y);
    };
    printf("sending lambda of %i bytes\n", sizeof(f));
    write(ConnectFD, (void*)&f, sizeof(f));
}


void recvlambda(int SocketFD)
{
    char buffer[1024];
    read(SocketFD, (void*)buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    function<int (void)> &f = *(function<int (void)>  *)buffer;
    f();
}

int server()
{
    printf("server\n");
    struct sockaddr_in stSockAddr;
    int SocketFD = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    if(-1 == SocketFD)
    {
        printf("can not create socket\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    memset(&stSockAddr, 0, sizeof(stSockAddr));

    stSockAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    stSockAddr.sin_port = htons(1100);
    stSockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    if(-1 == bind(SocketFD,(struct sockaddr *)&stSockAddr, sizeof(stSockAddr)))
    {
        printf("error bind failed\n");
        close(SocketFD);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if(-1 == listen(SocketFD, 10))
    {
        printf("error listen failed\n");
        close(SocketFD);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for(;;)
    {
        int ConnectFD = accept(SocketFD, NULL, NULL);

        if(0 > ConnectFD)
        {
            printf("error accept failed\n");
            close(SocketFD);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        /* perform read write operations ...*/
        sendlambda(ConnectFD);

        if (-1 == shutdown(ConnectFD, SHUT_RDWR))
        {
            printf("can not shutdown socket\n");
            close(ConnectFD);
            close(SocketFD);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        close(ConnectFD);
    }

    close(SocketFD);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}


int client()
{
    printf("client\n");
    struct sockaddr_in stSockAddr;
    int Res;
    int SocketFD = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    if (-1 == SocketFD)
    {
        printf("cannot create socket\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    memset(&stSockAddr, 0, sizeof(stSockAddr));

    stSockAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    stSockAddr.sin_port = htons(1100);
    Res = inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &stSockAddr.sin_addr);

    if (0 > Res)
    {
        printf("error: first parameter is not a valid address family\n");
        close(SocketFD);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else if (0 == Res)
    {
        printf("char string (second parameter does not contain valid ipaddress\n)");
        close(SocketFD);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (-1 == connect(SocketFD, (struct sockaddr *)&stSockAddr, sizeof(stSockAddr)))
    {
        printf("connect failed\n");
        close(SocketFD);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* perform read write operations ... */
    recvlambda(SocketFD);

    (void) shutdown(SocketFD, SHUT_RDWR);

    close(SocketFD);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if(argc>1 && strcmp(argv[1], "server")==0)
        server();
    else
        client();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You cannot simply `read` and `write` objects through sockets like that, except for trivially-copiable types, like those in C.  You know what happens if you send a `char*` that way right?  (Not what it points to, the pointer itself).  Same thing.

Comment: 1. you could (and should) have used `auto` to declare `f` 2. No need to make it mutable, you never modify internal state 3. you said it returns `int` but it doesn't. And of course, 4. You can't return an address of a local variable (which is what a lambda is, really)

Comment: Also note that the problem here is not the lambda itself, but the `function<int(void)>` holding state.

Comment: @MooingDuck The mutable and return int are my mistakes, I should have removed them. Nevertheless, it does not make any difference regarding my problem. Also your comment about char* is not valid here, because I am not making copies of any pointer.

Comment: @rosewater: Incorrect, you _are_ making copies of a pointer.  Imagine this now: `struct player {const char* name;}`  It should be obvious that reading/writing a `player` would also be invalid correct?  Well, `function<int(void)>` similarly contains a pointer inside of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a few more things and concluded that what I am trying to do is similar to serializing a lambda. [Serialize C++ functor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771842/serialize-c-functor)

It is not possible.

When the client code uses or defines the functor somewhere (in its own process space), and then receives some byte stream that are typecasted to that same functor, the code works. It somehow invokes that function in the client.

But if the client process does not have the functor block, and you try to typecast the byte stream to a functor, it does not work, you cannot invoke that functor.

It gets worse if its a closure, the variables captured by copy on the server cannot be mapped on the client. The variables in the data segment of the server process, they are being referred to in the functor in the server. When this functor is sent to the client, the client tries to access those variables given the memory address of the data segment. But those addresses are for the server process. So I get a read access violation.

It seems like I was trying to do code injection using lambdas, but that is not possible.

Answer (score 3):

In general you can't expect that making a bitwise copy of a complicated type such as `std::function` is going to work properly.

Here's what's likely happening: the `std::function` object created in the server process is holding a function pointer to the lambda you used to initialize it, which resides in the server process's memory. When the client process receives it, it tries to call this function pointer, which points into *a different process's address space* (that of the server process). It's not surprising that this segfaults.

But you are in undefined behaviour territory anyway, because you allocated an array of chars and then attempted to access it as though it were an `std::function` object.

Comment: Everything works fine if I don't use x and y. I thought when you copied variables to a lambda, it would make a 'copy' of them, not use references. And the client process tries to call the lambda in its own address space, not in the servers'.

Comment: It might work fine on your system, but that doesn't mean you should do it. In general it might or might not work, just like all other "undefined behaviour".

Comment: From this spec: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda

If the lambda-expression captures anything by copy (either implicitly with capture clause [=] or explicitly with a capture that does not include the character &, e.g. [a, b, c]), the closure type includes unnamed non-static data members, declared in unspecified order, that hold copies of all entities that were so captured.

Comment: Uh-huh, but the fact remains that copying the object representation of an `std::function` object into an array of chars does *not* produce another `std::function` object, in the view of the standard.

Comment: I was hoping a byte-wise copy would work and produce another std::function object. And it does seem to work if its not a closure.

Comment: Nevertheless, you shouldn't do it.

Answer (score 0):

The lambda is just another local which allocated on the sack of `sendlambda`.  The `&f` function is no different than taking the address of any other local declared in that function.  In this case though `f` is not a type which can simply be copied by value and re-hydrated in another frame (it's not a POD type).  This is why you are running into errors in `recvlambda`

Comment: The client does not get the address of a local on the stack in another process. It actually gets the functor code, and the addresses are mapped to the address space of the client process.

Comment: @rosewater it's still referring to the stack allocated lambda class

Comment: @JaredPar: I don't think he's sending the address of any stack allocated object.  He's passing a `std::function<int(void)>` as if it were trivially copiable, which holds a private copy of the lambda, either internal to itself or on the heap.

Comment: @JaredPar: MooingDuck is right. Passing the address of a local variable to `write()` is correct, if the local variable were a POD type -- `write()` simply copies the bytes of the variable, which is sufficient for POD types. The problem here is that `f`, of type `std::function<int(void)>` cannot be copied by just copying the bytes.